# How to erase a layer

Tags: google-maps

I have ...

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: var_url,
  suppressInfoWindows: false,
  map: map,
  preserveViewport: true
});
```

where `var_url` is a webservice where a date is passed so that what is returned  changes based on a date selection. The issue i am having is that the all the markers displayed stack as if the previous eyars markers are not removed.  Since i created the layer `ctaLayer` I was hoping it was going to be destroyed the next time I call this code but no..

Is there a way to check if `ctaLayer` exists and remove it before i call it again? I thought the local `var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer`  would do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ctaLayer.setMap(null);` removes the layer from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new KMLLayer each time, instead use a single KMLLayer and set a new `url` for the existing layer in subsequent calls:

```
ctaLayer.setUrl(var_url);
```

```js
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 33.7489954, lng:  -84.3879824},
          noClear:true
        }),
        select=map.getDiv().querySelector('select'),
        ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({preserveViewport:true,map:map});
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(select);
        
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],'change',function(){
          ctaLayer.setUrl('https://Services.oci.ga.gov/Geo_kml_Dust/default.aspx?Y='+this.value+'&t='+new Date().getTime());
          
          
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],'change')
      }
```

```css
html, body ,#map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="map">
        <select>
  <option>2016</option>
  <option>2015</option>
  <option>2014</option>
  <option>2013</option>
  <option>2012</option>
  <option>2011</option>
  <option>2010</option>
</select>
    </div>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: Does that also clear all the placemarks ? If so, that code is not successful  in doing that.  My webservices build part of the kml file this way... 
MyreturnString.Append("<Placemark style='width:250px'><name style='font-size:12pt;'>" + ds.Tables(Tablecount).Rows(index)("CompName") + "</name><description><![CDATA[<hr><p style='font-size:9pt; width:300px'><b>Plant Name: </b>" + ds.Tables(Tablecount).Rows(index)("Name") + "<p style='background-color:Red;color:#ffffff'>COMPLIANCE: NO for " + Var_QS +  etc......

Comment: A KMLLayer does not clear any placemark, it draws tiles based on your KML. When you set a new URL for a KMLLayer the tiles that have been drawn before will be removed,

Comment: Ah so then it leaves the placemarks behind - which is what I am observing.
function GetData(ayear)
{

var ctaLayer = "";
var var_year = ayear;
var var_url = 'https://Services.oci.ga.gov/Dust/default.aspx?Y=' + var_year

if (ctaLayer && ctaLayer.setMap) { ctaLayer.setMap(null); ctaLayer.setUrl(var_url); return}

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer
 ({
            url: var_url,
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            map: map,
            preserveViewport:true
        });

        ctaLayer.setMap(map)
}

Comment: It doesn't leave anything behind. A KMLLayer basically is only a set of tiles. There are no data available at all for Placemarks(except you click on a placemark)

Comment: Ok so in your view what would cause the placemarks to not be refreshed when the data is refreshed..... you can see the behavior here:

https://www.oci.ga.gov/safetymfg/DustMap.aspx

Comment: When refreshed data means a new url for KMLLayer: it should not happen. But when refreshed data means that a generated KML-file has been updated: google uses a cache to create the tiles, try to add a changing parameter(e.g. timestamp to the URL)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! They worked! Great Community!!